How to align VStack to top of View but under toolbar
I have put in a great deal of effort to find solutions to this before asking my question here in accordance with the rules. Unfortunately, all solutions previously answered have not worked for me. My seemingly simple task of having a VStack with elements that start at the top of the screen but under the toolbar is not happening as intended.
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Led Controller
//
// 
//

import SwiftUI
let R:CGFloat = 30
let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
let screenHeight = screenRect.size.height

struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View 
    {
        NavigationStack
        {
            ZStack
            {
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
                MainUI()
                
            }
            .toolbarBackground(Color.black, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar
            {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal)
                {
                    Text("LED Controller")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
                        .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(
                                colors: [.blue, .green, .brown, .pink],
                                startPoint: .leading,
                                endPoint: .trailing
                        ))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainUI: View
{
    var body: some View 
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading)
        {
            Text("Placeholder")
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: R)
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: screenWidth/2, height: 40))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

I have tried adding Spacer() in many different locations (After placeholder, after the vstack, after mainUI, ext.) but it seems to just hide the Placeholder off screen rather than push it to the top of the view. I also removed the toolbar completely and tried but it still hides the placeholder off screen where only a few pixels of the bottom of the text are visible. I have also tried the .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading) approach but it has no effect. I would greatly appreciate and help.
Edit:
I have legitimately no idea how this happened, but I changed the background image and it fixed itself. This is so weird.

https://google.github.io/swift/#braces

@loremipsum I don't know what I am supposed to do with that information. I don't think braces are the problem here.

They aren’t but it is a good to know thing, you’ll have better luck getting help with you follow SO rules for asking questions and follow standard conventions.

UIScreen has been deprecated for a while that could be the issue.

Can you show a screenshot of your desired result?

Where have you put your Spacer()? In the ZStack? Then this might be your error...

Hi, thanks for your help but I changed the background image and the issue magically fixed itself. I am not sure how that works but it did.

One way is to Wrap your MainUI() into a VStack but within your ZStack.
So your ZStack will look like this:
ZStack {
    Image("background")
       .resizable()
       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
    VStack {
        MainUI()
        Spacer()
      }
                
}

If you just put the Spacer in the ZStack, the UI will have no idea where to put your elements (there is probably a deterministic behavior, that I don't know).

You could also put the Spacer inside your MainUI VStack, however that might be confusing later if you want to find out, why your view is aligned like that.
It is worth mentioning that your Spacer MUST be within a VStack. Because only then SwiftUI will know to expand the Spacer vertically.

Thank You for your help, unfortunately what results is the Placeholder gets moved so far up it goes off screen.

That is not happening on my machine. It is just invisible, because it is black on black. Have you checked the font color? Try to add .foregroundStyle(.white)
